# Detecting random patterns in OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0

I want to apply Unsupervised learning on images through OpenCV and python to detect and categorise some special patterns in image and form different clutters.
[If this image is example how I can detect the yellow pattern?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSXaW.jpg)

Comment: I tried detecting for circles and was successful. But now I don't know how to detect different colours when I detect a circle. Or how can i detect a random pattern based on colour difference in images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting problem. If circle detection is showing good matches, you can consider the difference of color histograms in patches inside and outside the circles. Also worth investigating is the difference in edge histograms in small windows on the image.

To check the inside of the circles, you can take a square that is about 1.4 times wide as the circle radius, with the same center as the circle's center. For the outside, take a few squares about this size but are located further than the radius in x and y directions. I think approximate values like these should do.

Comment: I am not able to figure it out. Can you please elaborate on how to do so with a library in python or any other language?